# IntelliJ IDEA code analysis tool not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm a relatively new user of the IntelliJ IDEA, moved to it from Eclipse.
It has been working fine for several months, but now the code analysis plugin that performs analysis and precompiles the code on the fly, fails to work. It shows errors where they've been already fixed, not importing classes correctly. Restarting IDEA, updating to latest version and so on doesn't help. Did anybody face such problems and how did you resolve them?

Comment: Have you asked IntelliJ support for help?

Comment: Did you try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and Restart?

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, invalidating cache solved the problem

Answer (score 22):

Issue seems resolved, overall there's a couple of things that you can do when something is not working properly in Intellij:

1. Close intellij, open again.
2. Try building the project
3. Try invalidating the Caches and Restarting from the "File" menu
4. If using Maven try reimporting all modules and re-generating sources, these 2 features are right next to each other in the "Maven Project" window.
5. If all fails, delete the whole project and reimport it (for maven open the project again through the pom.xml for gradle the the build.gradle etc).

Comment: I can confirm this, number 3 worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Analyze > Inspect code   did the trick for me

Comment: This tip works with Scala project in 2020.3.2. The project is small but it has massive dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. I fixed it by setting the src folder in:-

`Project Structure` --> `Modules` --> Select your module --> `Sources` tab with blue underline --> Find your src folder and click on the Sources (blue icon).

`Apply` and `OK`.

Inspect a file and you should see the report now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with Swagger plugin and intelij analyzing just crashed. Disabling plugin solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. It turns out that I had the Power Save mode enabled. After disabling it, IntelliJ IDEA started working normally again. You can disable the Power Save mode from `File->Power Save Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was connected with the bug [IDEA-202867 - Code analysis fails on Java project when Groovy plugin is disabled](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202867).

Enabling Groovy plugin helped in my case.